# Flag post count not updating

Tags: support, flags, badges

I have flagged a new question and got `helpful` . When i see the profile i saw the below

[image]

I am seeing `66- helpful` flag and `65 /80 in left side panel` (Recommendation badge)

Why it is happening like this.

Comment: It's just caching, it will catch up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Caching.](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

The answer to these types of questions ("Why didn't a field update?" or "Why does this field not match that field when they should?") is always caching.

---

At the time of this post, your flag counts in both areas match again:

[image: Updated Flag Count]